# Acceder a un variable de un plantilla twig desde un bloque de javascript

Tags: symfony, twig

Quiero acceder a una variable que estoy generando en mi plantilla y la unica forma que se me ocurre es hacer esto, pero me salta un error que la variable "prueba" no existe

Hay una forma de lograr eso?

```
{% block name %}
    {% set prueba = "texto prueba" %}
    
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    <script>
        let text = {{prueba}}
        console.log(text)
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenes que mover prueba fuera del bloque, de lo contrario el scope se limita al bloque donde esta declarado, en este caso a `name`

Answer (score 0):

Pudieras asignar la variable twig como atributo data de algún elemento HTML real de tu vista, y desde el javascript obtenerla.

```
{% block name %}
   {% set variableTwig = "genero la variable en la vista twig o proviene del controller y no hay que generarla aquí" %}
    <div id="elementoVista" data-variable="{{ variableTwig }}"></div>        
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    <script>
        let text = document.getElementById("elementoVista")getAttribute('data-variable');
        console.log(text);
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```